# What did Tom say about shipbuilders back at Water 7?

Tags: one-piece

I'm looking for a quote by Tom to Franky at Water 7 in One Piece.

I remember Tom saying this to Franky, when he said he regrets making the battleships, and then Tom hit him.

It was something like

> A shipbuilder should never be ashamed of his works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?

On Chapter 356, when Spandam use Franky's ship to attack Shihousen:

[image]

there's a little bit difference on translate, as state on [wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Tom#Trivia):

> Tom's favorite phrase to say was "Do it with a Don!" ("with a Boom" in the Viz manga and "with Gusto" in the FUNimation dub)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I find it very inspiring in other subjects too.